# Python payroll generator

Tags: python

I've been given thee task to get all dates for payments. Let's say I have two dates:

```
date1 = date(2021,1,1)
date2 = date(2021,1,31)
```

So the logic is this: if it is the start of the month (`date1`) the payment should be for that month and if the date is the end of the month (`date2`) the payment should go for the next month. I have code like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, date
from dateutil.relativedelta import *

date1 = date(2021,1,1)
date2 = date(2021,1,31)

m = [date1, date2]

for date in m:
    date += relativedelta(months=1)
    print(date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'))
```

And the result is:

```
2021/02/01
2021/02/28
```

Which is basically correct, but I need the result to be like this:

```
2021/01 # payment for 1st month
2021/02 # payment for 2nd month
```

How can I do that?

**Solution** thanks to ***@deceze***:

```
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import *
from calendar import monthrange

date1 = date(2021,1,1)
date2 = date(2021,1,31)

m = [date1, date2]

for date in m:
    if monthrange(date.year, date.month)[1] == date.day:
        date += timedelta(days=1)
        print(date.strftime('%Y/%m'))
    elif monthrange(date.year, date.month)[1] != date.day:
        print(date.strftime('%Y/%m'))
```

Comment: Your post is really good but why is your post minus 1? I don't really know who does this, but really this community has a lot of crazy guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want this?

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
from calendar import monthrange

date2 = date(2021, 1, 31)

if monthrange(date2.year, date2.month)[1] == date2.day:
    date2 += timedelta(days=1)
```

If the day falls on the last day of a month (check with [`calendar.monthrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange)), increment it by one to be the first day of next month.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what i needed, thank you!